# ReCreate Content provider after deletion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I want to delete my sqlite db in the application due to some reason:

```
this.deleteDatabase(contentProvider.getDatabaseName());
```

I want to recreate my database file after that.

I read in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#onCreate%28%29) that :

```
onCreate is called for all registered content providers on the application main thread at application launch time.
```

And this is what I am doing to Create db in OnCreate at launch Time:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        try {
            contentProviderHelp = new ContentProviderHelp();

            userInfoTable = new UserInfoTable(contentProviderHelp);
            employeeInfoTable = new EmployeeInfoTable(contentProviderHelp);
            productsTable = new ProductsTable(contentProviderHelp);

            db = new DbMetadata(userInfoTable, employeeInfoTable, productsTable);
            ddlHelp = new DDLHelper(db);

            matcher = new UriMatch(userInfoTable, employeeInfoTable, productsTable, new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH));

            dbHelp = new DatabaseHelper(getContext(), DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, ddlHelp);
            projectionMaps = new ProjectionHelper(db);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can you help me how can I recreate ContentProvider after deletation of database file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a content provider to reset when manually deleting database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113783/how-to-force-a-content-provider-to-reset-when-manually-deleting-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a static function in you `DatabaseHelper` for this case and provide the current context as an argument. In your `DatabaseHelper` you can recreate the database